# SSIS Script Task Export Header only and create file if No Value shown

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am using C# script task in SSIS Script to export to a CSV File.
This is for example my data:
[image]

For 30 August 2022 my SSIS task successfully created the CSV file and all data is ok.

But on1 Sept 2022 no files have created, and when I checked the table, it showed no rows:
[image]

For 1 Sept I want the headers exported even if there is no data in table/view, and the CSV file is created.

This is my script task right now:

```
public void Main()
    {
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        try
        {

            //Declare Variables
            string FileNamePart = Dts.Variables["User::FlatFileNamePart"].Value.ToString();
            string DestinationFolder = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationFolder"].Value.ToString();
            string TableName = Dts.Variables["User::TableName"].Value.ToString();
            string FileDelimiter = Dts.Variables["User::FileDelimiter"].Value.ToString();
            string FileExtension = Dts.Variables["User::FileExtension"].Value.ToString();
            Int32 RecordCntPerFile = (Int32)Dts.Variables["User::RecordsPerFile"].Value;
            string RecordCntPerFileDecimal = RecordCntPerFile + ".0";


            //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["ADOAR"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);


            //Read distinct Group Values for each Excel Sheet
            string query = "select ceiling(count(*)/" + RecordCntPerFileDecimal + ") AS LoopCnt from " + TableName;
            decimal LoopCnt = 0;

            //Get the Count of Sheets need to be created
            SqlCommand cmd = myADONETConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            LoopCnt = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            int startRowCnt = 0;
            int endRowCnt = RecordCntPerFile;

            for (int fileloop = 1; fileloop <= LoopCnt; fileloop++)
            {


                //Load Data into DataTable from SQL ServerTable
                string queryString = "Select * from " +TableName ;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, myADONETConnection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);

                foreach (DataTable d_table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    string FileFullPath = DestinationFolder + "\\" + FileNamePart + "_" + datetime + FileExtension;

                    StreamWriter sw = null;
                    sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);

                    // Write the Header Row to File
                    int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
                    for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);
                        if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                    // Write All Rows to the File
                    foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                        {
                            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
                            }
                            if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                            {
                                sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                            }
                        }
                        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                    }

                    sw.Close();

                }
                startRowCnt += RecordCntPerFile;
                endRowCnt += RecordCntPerFile;
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }

        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            // Create Log File for Errors
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::LogFolder"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                "ErrorLog_" + datetime + ".log"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;


            }
        }




    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion
```

Any ideas why the files are not created?

Comment: Why are you using a script task at all to create the file? Why not just use a data flow with a file destination?

Comment: @Larnu because i have to create filename to with config date and name format and divided each csv only 600 rows, for example DATA_2022-09-01_PART1.csv and DATA_2022-09-01_PART2.csv  , .....

Comment: So use a For Each Loop, to *batch* the data.

Comment: Is the database working properly? it can lead to not being able to write to cvs.

Comment: @Housheng-MSFT database is fine, if i change select table within data inside, the file si created.

Comment: If the table has no data. Create a new table to store the current time and the cvs header as data written to cvs. Sorry this is also an idea.